# Populate array in Julia with Measurements.jl variables

Tags: julia

Newbie to Julia (coming from Matlab). I need to populate arrays with X ± Y variables, using Measurements.jl. Suggestions please? For example:

```
using Measurements
X = (40,) of values
Y = (40,) of uncertainties
Z = zeros(40)
for i in 1:40
Z[i] = X[i] ± Y[i]
end
```

The above loop doesn't work, nor does:

```
for i in 1:40
Z[i] = measurement(X[i],Y[i])
end
```

Nor does:

```
Z = X ± Y
```

or:

```
Z = measurement(X,Y)
```

but:

```
i = 1
Z = X[i] ± Y[i]
Z = measurement(X[i],Y[i])
```

both work, though of course returning only one Z

Comment: Hello!. please correct the codes creating `X` and `Y` as something is missing there.

Answer (score 2):

Just solved my own question. Syntax is:

```
Z = X .± Y
```